# How to Keep Script running for Auto Print and then Delete

Tags: vbscript

So far i got the part of auto print.

I need to keep the script **running** in the back, to look for any .pdf that it can find on a targeted folder for example "downloads", that way whenever i download a .pdf, it will **print** it and then **delete** the file.

```
TargetFolder = "\\USER\FOLDER" 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(TargetFolder) 
Set colItems = objFolder.Items 
For Each objItem In colItems 
objItem.InvokeVerbEx ("Print") 
Next
```

Comment: You could just use Task Schedular to run the script to a schedule of your choosing.

Comment: @Lankymart i couldnt find in what part they address the print then delete code.

Comment: You have your code I was simply pointing you to how to run it in a scheduled fashion that means it doesn't have to constantly run in some low performant over complex scripted loop. If your missing the delete part of the script, this can be accomplished easily with the `FileSystemObject`. You'll will find plenty of existing questions that cover this in detail.

Comment: Here is a [good example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9012529/692942) of question that deals with deleting files using the `FileSystemObject`. If you came here posting a question expecting it to be written for you, than you came to the wrong place.

Comment: @Lankymart
On the contrary my friend, thanks for all the help, when you help a user many benefit from a question answered in the long run, since users can see a consolidated and functional example.
good day.

Comment: Wow I was posting the working code and it is closed, bad luck.

Comment: Not when it's a duplicate or composite of multiple questions that have already been answered. Please review [ask] before posting.